# how to navigate to a new page in an onsubmit function react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-stack

I have a form that should store data and pass it as a parameter while navigating to a new screen. I have it structured like so. The formik form:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          first_name: '',
          last_name: '',
        }}
        // Form submission action
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          const d = addData(values);
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Cart', {
            screen: 'Process Payment',
            params: {data: d},
          });
        }}>
        {(props) => (
          <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : null}
            style={{flex: 1, width: '100%'}}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.inner}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="first name"
                onChangeText={props.handleChange('first_name')}
                value={props.values.first_name}
              />
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="last name"
                onChangeText={props.handleChange('last_name')}
                value={props.values.last_name}
              />
              <View style={[{width: '90%', margin: 10, alignSelf: 'center'}]}>
                <Button
                  title="place order"
                  color="maroon"
                  onPress={props.handleSubmit}
                  style={{padding: 3, width: '80%'}}
                />
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Onsubmit function:

```
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          const d = addData(values);
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Cart', {
            screen: 'Process Payment',
            params: {data: d},
          });
        }}>
```

My Error:
  `Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')]`
I'm not sure how to navigate to a new screen within the onsubmit function

Comment: Please add more of the component code here as it is not sufficient enough to get the root cause. My guess would be that you need to bind the function to the class instance or use babel plugin to do that .

Comment: I added the entire form. Does this help?

Comment: I feel like `this` keyword is not needed here. Can you try `props.navigation.navigate` as it looks like you are accessing values from props on other different places. Are you using hooks or class component ?

Comment: I'm using hooks. I believe those props are specific to the formik form whereas the navigation prop isn't. I'll try it though

Comment: This worked thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          const d = addData(values);
          props.navigation.navigate('Cart', {
            screen: 'Process Payment',
            params: {data: d},
          });
        }}>
```

I took out the "this" and just called props.navigation.navigate